# How to change value of class in another class?

Tags: html, css, joomla

Here's some code:

```
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div class="cell_pad">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to tell to css, that `you have to change value of class "cell_pad" which is in id="one"`?

.cell_pad is repeated a few times in code, but I've to change `one occurence of this class.`

I'm using `sparky framework` for joomla.

I've tried like that in my stylesheet, but it doesn't effect:

```
#one > .cell_pad{}
```

Comment: have you tried #one .cell_pad{}

Comment: a space is for descendant elements while `>` is for direct children

Comment: A class has no "values". An HTML element can be styled with CSS rules applied to it, by example by using a selector with this class. And in these rules there are instructions made of `property: value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
#one .cell_pad{}
```

that Selects all .cell_pad elements inside #one elements, you sould take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should use this :

```
#one .cell_pad 
{
}
```

This will select all the .cell_pad elements in #one element